# Do I have to call super in NSManagedObject didTurnIntoFault?

Tags: cocoa, core-data

do I have to call super in `didTurnIntoFault`? I couldn't find any directions in the documentation.

```
- (void)didTurnIntoFault {
  [super didTurnIntoFault]; // Do I have to call super?
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you subclass NSManagedObject and override -didTurnIntoFault, you **must** send the message to super.

See the [Subclassing Notes](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObject_Class/Reference/NSManagedObject.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001171-235678) of the NSManagedObject class reference.

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't believe so. The purpose of `didTurnIntoFault` is to give you a chance to release any instance variables (particularly for transient values) you might be holding. While it is meant to be used as a replacement for `dealloc` for `NSManagedObject` subclasses, that's because the life cycle of an `NSManagedObject` is quite different from an ordinary `NSObject`. So, although it serves much the same purpose as `dealloc`, it doesn't work in quite the same way.

Of course, if you subclass your own subclass of `NSManagedObject`, you will need to call `[super didTurnIntoFault]` there.

That said, I would imagine that `NSManagedObject`'s implementation is probably a no-op, so I sincerely doubt there's any harm in invoking it anyway. Also, because there's no harm in it, it may help you to remember to call it when it really does matter.

Comment: I agree with you. The reason why I'm asking is to play it safe.